# Rails simple_form with multiple submit buttons always returning final button as commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a rails form with two submission types, however regardless of which I select, the commit value is always set as the last button.

```
  <%= simple_form_for @open_position do |op| %>
    <div class="modal-body" data-modal-body>
```

...

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">
    <%= t('buttons.cancel') %>
  </button>
  <%= op.submit t('buttons.continue_add_candidate'),
      class: 'btn btn-default',
      data: {
        ui_disable: 'createOpening',
        ui_verify_confirm: ''
      } %>
  <%= op.submit t('buttons.continue'),
      class: 'btn btn-default',
      data: {
        ui_disable: 'createOpening',
        ui_verify_confirm: ''
      } %>
</div>
```

with the following, I'll get

```
"commit"=>"Continue"
```

in params regardless of which button is pressed. The only special case about this is that it's happening in a modal, I suppose. Has anyone ever experienced something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a parameter name: 'continue'

```
<%= op.submit t('buttons.continue_add_candidate'),
      class: 'btn btn-default',
      name: 'continue',
      data: {
        ui_disable: 'createOpening',
        ui_verify_confirm: ''
      } %>
```

then capture it in the controller